# django file not found error: when javascript file inside static directory trying to access another file in the static directory?

Tags: javascript, django

I am doing one django project. And I am able to access the "custom.js" file from static folder path.This is a line inside my "index.html" file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'crypto_app/js/custom.js' %}" ></script>
```

But inside "custom.js" file it is using this :

```
$(window).ready(function() {
'use strict';
$.vegas('slideshow', {
  backgrounds:[
    { src: 'images/bg-slider/bg-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'images/bg-slider/bg-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'images/bg-slider/bg-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
})();
```

And hence, due to wrong file address, I am not able to access the images. And it is showing file not found.

Is there some django way to declare path of images as variable and accessing it from the "custom.js" file? Given below is my directory structure :

```
|   admin.py
|   apps.py
|   models.py
|   tests.py 
|   tree.txt
|   urls.py
|   views.py
|   
+---migrations
|   |   __init__.py|           
+---static
|   \---crypto_app      
|       +---css
|       |           
|       +---fonts      
|       +---images  
|       |   \---bg-slider
|       |           bg-1.jpg
|       |           bg-2.jpg
|       |           bg-3.jpg
|       |           
|       \---js
|               custom.js               
+---templates
|   \---crypto_app
|           index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to answer your question, no there is no Django specific thing that makes you get paths for these images OOTB in your JavaScript file.
Django would force you to access via HTML (as shown in example #2).

There's most likely some Django app that you can install.

Now on to solving your conundrum.
Since you're using the `{% static %}` template tag to load your JavaScript you would need to do something similar.

Of course there's a few ways to make this happen:

1) Hardcode the URL, `{% static %}` basically concats your `STATIC_URL` together with the path you've supplied. So take the same URL and append it to the image urls. Assuming `STATIC_URL` is set to `/static/` your new hardcoded urls would be something along the lines of `/static/images/bg-slider/bg-1.jpg` and so on.

2) Create an options object and tack it onto `window`. In your `index.html`:

```
<script>
    window.options = {
        staticUrl: {{ STATIC_URL }},
    };
</script>
```

Then use this in your JS code

```
backgrounds:[
    { src: `${window.options.staticUrl}images/bg-slider/bg-1.jpg`, fade:1000 },
}
```

Naturally if you have just the one place you do this, hardcoding would be the easiest option for you at this point in time. :)

Happy hacking!

Comment: thanks for such quick response. But still I am getting the following error:  " Not Found: /crypto_app/${window.options.staticUrl}crypto_app/images/bg-slider/bg-1.jpg"    and    "GET /crypto_app/{window.options.staticUrl}crypto_app/images/bg-slider/bg-1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2654. Please resolve this.

Comment: I was using javascript template literals, notice the ````, backticks. If you can't support that for browser reasons then a normal string concatenation is something for you.

Comment: oh! it means the browser is not supporting that literal. Well! for the temporary solution, I have copied the whole "custom.js" file in place of its link.   I think that concatenation would do the job. Thanks for your valuable response. @Mr. Andersson